# error in Javascript in storing the array value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

output of

```
result[0].brand_id  = ["59df686fe30af41be049417f","59df68eca39cf51b40c566ab"]
```

and i want to store the value find by these id in single storage 'brand'

and my code is

```
    var data = {};
    data['brands'] = [];

    async.each(result[0].brand_id, function (brand,callback) {

        Brand.findById(brand,function(err,result){
            if(err){
                callback("there is an error");
            }
            //console.log(result.brand_name);
            data['brands'] = {
                brand: result.brand_name,
                dosage: result.dosage_id
            };
            console.log(data); // it is correct but but shows two single storage
        });
        callback();
    },function (err,data) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(data); // it show output undefined
    });
```

I want my output as

```
    { brands: 
   [ { brand: 'a', dosage: ["59df686ee30af41be049417e"] },
     { brand: 'b', dosage: ["59df68eca39cf51b40c566aa"] } ] }
```

I am stuck here,please solve this.

Comment: Are you sure that is the output you want? An array cannot have a key. It must be an object inside the array.

Comment: yes because i have to send this data in frontend.

Comment: What i mean is, you can't have [ key : value]. You can either have {key : value} or {key: [values]}. These keys can be nested as well.

Comment: sorry for output..i am editing it

Comment: @ParijatPurohit  ..this the output,that i want

Comment: Editing my answer as well, wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to create `data['brand']` as an array and will have to push in values inside it.

**A sample solution:**

```
if(!data['brand']) data['brand'] = []; // to check if it is the first time you are inserting inside data['brand'], in which case it needs to be initialized.
data['brand'].push({
            brand: result.brand_name,
            dosage: [result.dosage_id]
        });
```

Comment: these two are different or use at same time

Comment: I think second choice is what you really want. Try doing it with my answer and see itlf it helps :)

Comment: please see again the output what i want.  @Parijat

Comment: it gives same output 'undefined'

Comment: Can you remove the data argument from the second function and make it like `function (err) {`?

Comment: it give   -  { brand: [] }

Comment: Can you put the callback() inside the findById call as well? Currently it is outside that?

Comment: @RupeshYadav Glad I could help. :)
BTW do understand why I asked you to change those things: will help you in getting a better understanding of async and javascript :)

Comment: That callback is like a marker function for async which lets async know that your  asynchronous method inside each has finished executing. As your findById is asynchronous, you put callback inside it and thus, callback is called when findById is finished.